# Regular expressions and php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Say I have a string like this:

```
$string = 'The /*quick*/ brown /*fox*/ jumped over the lazy /*dog*/.';
```

How can I use a regular expression to find the occurrences of /* */ and replace each value like so:

```
/*quick*/ with the value of $_POST['quick']
/*fox*/ with the value of $_POST['fox']
/*dog*/ with the value of $_POST['dog']
```

I have tried with preg_replace using this pattern: `~/\*(.+)\*/~e`

But it does not seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern `(.+)` is too greedy. It will find the longest match i.e. `quick*/ brown /*fox*/ jumped over the lazy /*dog`, so it won't work.

If there will be no `*` appear between `/*` and `*/`, then use:

```
preg_replace('|/\*([^*]+)\*/|e', '$_POST["$1"]', $string)
```

Otherwise, use a lazy quantifier:

```
preg_replace('|/\*(.+?)\*/|e', '$_POST["$1"]', $string)
```

Example: http://www.ideone.com/hVUNA.

Comment: `preg_replace('|/\*([^*]+)\*/|e', '$_POST["$1"]', $string)` Beautifully put

Comment: preg_replace('|/\*([^*]+)\*/|e', '$_POST["$1"]', $string) did the job great,thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can generalize this (PHP 5.3+, dynamic functions):

```
$changes = array('quick' => $_POST['quick'],
                 'fox'   => $_POST['fox'],
                 'dog'   => $_POST['dog']   );

$string = 'The /*quick*/ brown /*fox*/ jumped over the lazy /*dog*/.';

echo preg_replace(
        array_map(function($v){return'{/\*\s*'.$v.'\s*\*/}';}, array_keys($changes)),
        array_values($changes),
        $string
     );
```

**if you want to have fine control** over what gets replaced. Otherwise, [KennyTM already solved this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548844/regular-expressions-and-php/3548888#3548888).

Regards

rbo